# Deducting template parameter for iterator constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, metaprogramming

I am trying to create a constructor for my class which takes iterators of containers as arguments and creates another type of container (suppose something like a span from an array).

I would like to use a template deduction guide to support this and I was successful for non-cv qualified iterators, but it failed to deduct when I passed const-iterators:

```cpp
// Deduction guide
<template typename Iterator>
Foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end) -> Foo<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>;
```

```cpp
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
Foo foo(v.begin(), v.end());
Foo otherFoo(v.cbegin(), v.cend());  // fails deduction
```

With a bit of trial and error, I was able to make it work with this deduction guide:

```cpp
template <class Iterator>
Foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end) -> Foo<std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>,
                             typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type,
                             typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type const>>;
```

But as I am compiling with C++20, I don't understand why this works. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), `std::iterator_traits::value_type` should be stripped of cv-qualification.

As a test, using the same environment I made the following test:

```cpp
// test with non-const iterator
if (std::is_const_v<std::iterator_traits<decltype(v.begin())>::value_type>)
{
    std::cout << "it is const" << std::endl;
} else 
{
    std::cout << "It is not const" << std::endl;
}

// test with const iterator
if (std::is_const_v<std::iterator_traits<decltype(v.cbegin())>::value_type>)
{
    std::cout << "it is const" << std::endl;
} else 
{
    std::cout << "It is not const" << std::endl;
}
```

And got the expected: both are printing that "It is not const". So why would the template guide above work?

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/9sMrEjG5v)

#### Example class

```cpp
template <class T>
class Foo{
  public:
    template <class Iterator>
    Foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    : mData(&*begin) 
    , mSize(std::distance(begin, end)) {}

    T operator[](std::size_t i) {
        return *(mData+i); 
    }  
  private:
    T *mData; 
    std::size_t mSize;
}; 

// Template deduction guides
template <class Iterator>
Foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end) -> Foo<std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>,
                             typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type,
                             typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type const>>;
```

Comment: *So why would the template guide above work?*  because you are using `T = value_type const`(the false branch of `conditional_t`) for BOTH `begin()` and `cbegin()` case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So why would the template guide above work?

Since `value_type` is always *cv*-unqualified, this makes `std::conditional_t` always false, so your reduction guide is equivalent to

```
template <class Iterator>
Foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end) -> 
  Foo<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type const>;
```

which means that `Foo(v.begin(), v.end())` is actually deduced to be `Foo<const int>` instead of `Foo<int>`.

The appropriate definition in C++20 would be

```
template <class Iterator>
Foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end) -> 
  Foo<std::remove_reference_t<std::iter_reference_t<Iterator>>>;
```